# Azure Database - Missing dbmanager role - Database Migration

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I am attempting to:

> To copy your database to a new database on a different logical server

as detailed on this page:

[How to: Use Database Copy (Azure SQL Database)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff951631.aspx#TsqlProcedureCrossServer)

I have made sure I have the correct username and password for the source database and it's a dbo.

I have created a new user in the destination database in the master database with the same username and password.

The instructions say that to enable the new user to create a database it must be a member of the role "dbmanager" role.

But, there is no "dbmanager" role listed in my destination master database.

Ultimately I want to be able to run the following command:

> CREATE DATABASE NewDatabase AS COPY OF abc12345.OldDatabase;

which is currently giving me the error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Why haven't I got a "dbmanager" role please? Or should I be using some other role that does already exist.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

The only roles I have in the database, created through the Azure portal, are shown below...

[image]

Comment: When you run a select * from sys.database_principals  in your Master database it doesn't include dbmanager?

Comment: @MikeWo that's right. it's not there. I have added an image showing what roles are present.

Comment: I would delete the target server and recreate it.  Perhaps it was a provisioning problem that caused the role to not be created?

Comment: If you don't have any other databases on this server then what Simon suggested above would be what I would do. Otherwise I'd open a support ticket as that role should be there.